# Owl Carousel does not Autoplay

Tags: javascript, html

i am using Owl Carousel in my site

and it does not auto play this is the link of the site
[link of the site](http://www.dryousryelsafty.com/sayedddd/adel/index2.html)

this is the html code

```js
<script src="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
 autoplay : 5000,
 navigation : false, // Show next and prev buttons
 slideSpeed : 300,
 paginationSpeed : 400,
 singleItem:true

});
$("#owl-demo2").owlCarousel({
autoplay : 5000,
 navigation : false, // Show next and prev buttons
 slideSpeed : 300,
 paginationSpeed : 400,
 singleItem:true

});
$("#owl-demo3").owlCarousel({
autoplay : 5000,
 navigation : false, // Show next and prev buttons
 slideSpeed : 300,
 paginationSpeed : 400,
 singleItem:true

});

});
</script>
```

```html
<div id="owl-demo2" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

     <div class="item">
       <img src="img/k1.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="" />
       <div class="capt text-center">
        قرية بوذيب
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
       <img src="img/k1.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="" />
       <div class="capt text-center">
        قرية بوذيب
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
       <img src="img/k1.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="" />
       <div class="capt text-center">
        قرية بوذيب
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Feel free to check the link and see if you can find any problems. All help is appreciated! Here is the link to the own Carousel documentation 
http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#how-to
thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

In the example you have `autoplay : 5000` but in your website you don't have it.

Update this code in your website to fix the problem:

```
$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    autoplay : 5000,
    navigation : false, // Show next and prev buttons
    slideSpeed : 300,
    paginationSpeed : 400,
    singleItem:true

});
$("#owl-demo2").owlCarousel({
    autoplay : 5000,
    navigation : false, // Show next and prev buttons
    slideSpeed : 300,
    paginationSpeed : 400,
    singleItem:true

});
$("#owl-demo3").owlCarousel({
    autoplay : 5000,
    navigation : false, // Show next and prev buttons
    slideSpeed : 300,
    paginationSpeed : 400,
    singleItem:true

});
```